# Convert json mapping object to managed csv row using bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, json

**I have json mapping under `properties` key as below in a file Customer.json,**

```
{
    "customer": {
        "properties": {
            "customerId": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which I want to convert into following with `key` and `displayName` duplicated and `type` from above mapping,

```
field(key: 'customerId',     displayName: 'customerId', type: 'String')
field(key: 'name',           displayName: 'name',       type: 'String')
```

I hit and tried **bash + python** as below assuming it fetched customer key first and loops inside properties ,

```
$ cat Customer.json | python -c 'import sys; import simplejson as json; \
print "\n".join( [i["properties"] for i in json.loads( sys.stdin.read() )["customer"]] )'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I'm open to other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing such structured data is best done using a dedicated parser, just as you are doing. However, in this particular case, it is simple enough that you could do:

```
$ grep -B 1 '"type":' Customer.json | tr $'"' $"'" | sed 's/[:,]//g' | 
    awk '{print "field(key: "$1",\tdisplayName: "$1",\t type: "$NF")"}' RS="--"
```

Which returns:

```
field(key: 'customerId',    displayName: 'customerId',   type: 'string')
field(key: 'name',  displayName: 'name',     type: 'string')
```

Answer (score 1):

The error seems clear to me, the variable "i" is a string as the `for` loop iterates over the value of "customer" dict/mapping. That value is a dict/mapping itself and iterating over it will get you the succesion of the list of keys (i.e. ["properties"].

```
cat Customer.json |  python -c 'import sys; import simplejson as json; \
print "\n".join( [i for i in json.loads( sys.stdin.read() )["customer"]["properties"] ] )'
```

will give you

```
 customerid
 name
```

and the following should get you closer to your goal:

```
cat Customer.json |  python -c 'import sys; import simplejson as json; \
print "\n".join( ["{} {}".format(k, v) for k,v in json.loads( sys.stdin.read() )["customer"]["properties"].iteritems() ] )'
```

which gives:

```
customerId {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'}
name {'index': 'not_analyzed', 'type': 'string'}
```

From there I would recommend you actually make the python in a script. You will have to decide on how to get from `string` to `String` and do the additional  formatting. A multiliner is always more easy to debug (case proven by your Question) and maintainable and gives more meaningful (line numbers) error messages.

Answer (score 0):

With `jq`:

```bash
jq -r '.customer.properties | to_entries[] | 
    "field(key: \u0027\(.key)\u0027, displayName: \u0027\(.key)\u0027, type: \u0027\(.value.type)\u0027)"' Customer.json
```

This turns the `properties` values into a list objects with keys `key` and `value`.  Each `key` will have the value of the `properties` keys (i.e., `customerId` and `name`), and each `value` will have the value that is the `properties` sub-object.

Given one such entry, the `key` value and the `type` value of the `value` entry are extracted and inserted into the text string template.  Each `\u0027` that you see in the string is a single-quote character.

The output of this, given your example input file, would be

```
field(key: 'customerId', displayName: 'customerId', type: 'string')
field(key: 'name', displayName: 'name', type: 'string')
```